# I have to run `startx` on boot to have a window manager, how can I fix this?

Tags: linux, debian, startx

I've had Debian Wheezy for a long time and decided to upgrade yesterday to Jessie, a few things I did wrong, I ran `autoremove` because I was careless and a few things happened.

1) I have to run `startx` to start the window manager / GUI every time I boot

and

2) I have to run `ifup eth0` to get internet access. Basically I have to manually get DHCP to assign me an IP address every time.

How could I fix this so that I can avoid doing both every time I boot into linux?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you've removed your login manager. Install a login manager(i.e. SLiM) and append ifup eth0 to your .xinitrc file.

Comment: Also known as the display manager.
See https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/display_manager

Answer (score 0):

Edit your `.bashrc` file to include the following commands at the bottom of the script.

`startx
ifup eth0`

It may not be the most elegant but it'll fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Install a display manager[1](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/display_manager). If it is not working or you already have one installed, then run `dpkg-reconfigure <name of display manager>`[2](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=dpkg-reconfigure)

Select your display manager in the configuration screen and you should be good to go.

Add `auto eth0` to `/etc/network/interfaces`.[3](https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration#Setting_up_an_Ethernet_Interface)